# How to call a dynamically created label from its associated dynamically created button's click in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, buttonclick, dynamic-controls

I have a tab in a form. On form load, I am getting text from a text file line by line and displaying them as labels on a form Tabcontrol Tabpage along with dynamically displaying buttons beside them. Now on those buttons click I want to copy the text in the associated labels. Can anyone suggest what to put in the `Nextbtn_Click` event?

```
Dim FILE_NAME As String = "D:\1.txt"    
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim i As Integer = 1
    For Each line As String In System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(FILE_NAME)
        Dim NextLabel As New Label
        Dim Nextbtn As New Button
        NextLabel.Text = line
        Nextbtn.Text = "Copy"
        NextLabel.Height = 22
        Nextbtn.Width = 55
        Nextbtn.Height = 22
        NextLabel.BackColor = Color.Yellow
        TabPage2.Controls.Add(NextLabel)
        TabPage2.Controls.Add(Nextbtn)
        NextLabel.Location = New Point(10, 10 * i + ((i - 1) * NextLabel.Height))
        Nextbtn.Location = New Point(120, 10 * i + ((i - 1) * Nextbtn.Height))
        AddHandler Nextbtn.Click, AddressOf Me.Nextbtn_Click
        i += 1
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub Nextbtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the assc. label in the tag property and you can cast it back when you click on the button. The sender object is the button that is currently clicked.

```
Dim FILE_NAME As String = "D:\1.txt"    
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim i As Integer = 1
    For Each line As String In System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(FILE_NAME)
        Dim NextLabel As New Label
        Dim Nextbtn As New Button
        Nextbtn.Tag = NextLabel
        NextLabel.Text = line
        Nextbtn.Text = "Copy"
        NextLabel.Height = 22
        Nextbtn.Width = 55
        Nextbtn.Height = 22
        NextLabel.BackColor = Color.Yellow
        TabPage2.Controls.Add(NextLabel)
        TabPage2.Controls.Add(Nextbtn)
        NextLabel.Location = New Point(10, 10 * i + ((i - 1) * NextLabel.Height))
        Nextbtn.Location = New Point(120, 10 * i + ((i - 1) * Nextbtn.Height))
        AddHandler Nextbtn.Click, AddressOf Me.Nextbtn_Click
        i += 1
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub Nextbtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim s As String = DirectCast(DirectCast(sender, Button).Tag, Label).Text
End Sub
```

Comment: But suppose instead of copying I want to delete the text from text file, using another dynamically created delete button. Could you suggest me something then how to interact with the label text?

Comment: Store the `filepath` in the `Tag` property, then you can access it from the delete button with same technique.

Comment: DonA can you help me with another issue here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18808904/dynamic-button-click-event-not-able-to-call-a-function-vb-net

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Clicked(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim b As Button = DirectCast(sender, Button)
    TextBox2.Text = b.Name
    Clipboard.SetText(b.Name)

End Sub
```

Comment: Please don't only post code. Try to explain how you solved the question etc. | And welcome to StackOverflow!